# Reload the app as if it was killed when entering foreground

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I have an app I made using the `Tab bar` template (so in the app there's a storyboard and two viewcontrollers).

Sometimes this app could enter background (eg. the user presses the Home button, than opens the app again): is it possible to completely reload(*) the app when `applicationDidBecomeActive` in the `appDelegate` fires?

(*) completely reload means the Tab bar controller `viewDidLoad` fires again: the app should behave as if it has been killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am sure you have a very solid reason do that because otherwise its a perfect recipe for disaster :D

Anyway you can achieve it by reset the rootView Controller of your app in `applicationDidBecomeActive` using

```
    self.window?.rootViewController = nil
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Or if your Tab bar controller is not the rootViewController, you can instantiate a new tab bar controller and load it while discarding the old one.

Comment: I'm looking for various different solutions before taking a particular decision   :-)  (the tabbar controller is the rootviewcontroller in the tab bar default template)

Comment: @3000 : May I know why would u want that ? Why do you wanna complete reload the app??

Comment: It's because at the moment the app is fairly simple but it could grow. In this case, "grow" means there could be, in a near future, dozens of deeply nested viewcontrollers giving access to other viewcontrollers (master->detail->detail->detail...). This means the user can reload the app where he left BUT, since data of that particular viewcontroller is "interesting" for a couple of hours on sunday, he can find himself "trapped" in an unuseful "state" of the app

Comment: @3000 : So for that u don't need to reload whole app, add a observer for application will enter foreground in each VC view will appear and remove in viewwilldisappear, so when user puts app in back ground in some detail page, that page has its observer on, and when user relaunches the app or user navigates back, each VC will make a web service call and reloads its data to most updated state and updates UI in viewwillappear. This is a very basic issue with all the apps and not all apps reload the app,

Comment: If you have a issue where you are showing the detail of a object in one of detail page while app goes to background and when app comes back to foreground object itself might not be valid anymore and u are simply showing some stale data, what you can do is pop to safe view controller, like listing screen or some screen in app which does not show stale data and reloads its data every time it comes to foreground rather than reloading whole app

Comment: Anything is very interesting, thanks, I'll think on it

Comment: @3000: There are also cases where app when brought to foreground makes a web service call in background and on realizing that the detail they are showing is no longer valid they simply either pop/dismiss the detail page showing appropriate message on screen, like product no linger available etc :) think through that as well